# I have a collection in mongo db which is of 89.8 gb and I want to extract all the elements of the collection

Tags: python, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Here is my piece of code where am getting the elements.

`

```
client = MongoClient('localhost:27017')
 db = client.cdiscount
 for e in db.train_data.find({}, {"category_id": 1, "imgs": 1}):
    img_arr = []
    category_id = e["category_id"]
    if str(category_id) in list(img_dict.keys()):
       img_arr = img_dict[str(category_id)]
    img_arr += [imread(io.BytesIO(img["picture"])) for img in e["imgs"]]
    img_dict[str(category_id)] = img_arr
    if len(list(img_dict.keys())) > 500:
        print("Saving images...")
        save_as_numpy(img_dict)
        img_dict = {}
```

`

I have a RAM of 32 gb the code works fine initially, but as the cache gets filled up it gets slow and ultimately hangs when the memory is full. Is there any way to retrieve all the documents in a collection whose size is bigger than the memory?

Comment: the best option is to use generator function that gets your data and does not save much in memory. You dictionary size keeps getting bigger and bigger and hence you hit the issue of memory overflow which can be avoided. can you tell us which part of the code consumes your memory? does the save_as_numpy run even for once?

Comment: Yes. save_as_numpy() is getting executed properly, program is getting slow  during the find() method